# Proving the definition of sequence convergency

Tags: real-analysis

Show: $x_n \to x$ in $\mathbf N$ if and only if there exists $N$ with $x_n = x$, all $n \geq N$.

I was asked to prove this. I couldn't find the proof in the textbooks. Can somebody proves it for me please? Thank you.

Comment: Consider $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$ in the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of convergence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $x_n \rightarrow x$ in $\mathbb{N}$. Then, we know that given $\epsilon>0$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n>N \implies |x_n-x|<\epsilon$

Now, note that for $\epsilon=\frac{1}{4}$, for example, $|x_n-x|<\frac{1}{4} \implies x_n=x$. Since this applies $\forall n>N$, and $N$ is finite, we have that $x_n$ is constant after some point.

The other direction is trivial : Suppose there is $N$ such that $x_n=x \ \forall n > N$, for any $\epsilon>0$, take $n=N$, and obviously the limit conditions are followed, so it follows that $x_n \rightarrow x$.

Note that there is nothing special about $\mathbb{N}$: the same argument would work with any discrete set, like $\mathbb{Q}$. What is special about such sets is that all their points are somewhat spread out, far apart : to be precise, the sets $\mathbb{N} $ and $ \mathbb{Q}$ have no interior.

Any set can be divided into connected components, where the meaning of connected should be intuitive (connected is like a continuous region). You will see that for $\mathbb{R}$, the whole set is connected, while for $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$, it isn't. In fact, the so called connected components of these sets are individual points. You can prove (it is simple) that for a sequence to converge to a point, it must eventually lie entirely in the connected component of the limit. In this case, this directly translates to $x_n=x$ after some time. This is a different proof of the same fact.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x_n\rightarrow x$ and that there is no such $N$. Then I can take a subsequence of $x_n$'s such that each one of them is at least $x+1$. Such subsequence must converge to $x$. Take $\epsilon = \frac12$ as suggested above. Contradiction.